# Java.lang.RuntimeException: [Simba][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature in BigQuery Talend

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

I am new to Talend. I am trying to load data from SQL Server to BigQuery. I am getting error (see image). Using same Connection I am able to read data. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to share any other code or details? There's not a lot to work with here..

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Can you please tell me what info are you looking for?

I am trying to load data from Sql Server to BigQuery from Talend Open Studio Bigdata version V7.1.1.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/
JDBC 4.1-compatible & JDBC 4.2-compatible.

I can able to connect Google Bog Query and I can read and export data from Google Big Query table data to csv file using Talenend job. But i am not able to write data from SQL Server to Big Query. 

Please let me know if any more information req

Used simba drivers provided by google cloud platform